# Iterating inputvo and getting common records for all uers.i have to do same for 100 more lists.suggest me generic method for all lists

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, dictionary

Iterate InputVO and get common records for all users storing in map have to do same for multiple vOs

```
public List<InputVO> getInputDataFromDB() { 
        List<InputVO> list = dao.getInputVO();  
        Map<String, List<InputVO>> userMap = new HashMap<>();
        list.forEach((inputVO) -> { 
            String userId = inputVO.getUserId();    
            if (userMap.containsKey(userId){
                userMap.get(userId).add(inputVO);
            }else { List<InputVO> results = new ArrayList<>();
                results.add(inputVO);
                userMap.put(userId, results);
            }
   });
}
```

Comment: suggest me generic method for all lists

Answer (score 0):

You could use `putIfAbsent()` method instead of `containsKey()`. In this way there will be less code lines and easier to read.

```
public List<InputVO> getInputDataFromDB() { 
    List<InputVO> list = dao.getInputVO();  
    Map<String, List<InputVO>> userMap = new HashMap<>();
    list.forEach((inputVO) -> { 
        String userId = inputVO.getUserId();
        userMap.putIfAbsent(userId,new ArrayList());    
        userMap.get(userId).add(inputVO);
  });
}
```

Comment: but i have to do same for outputVO. How can i reuse this method for inputVO and outputVO. i dont want to write two same methods for diferent VOs

Comment: So the `dao` object has 2 methods ? `getInputVO()` and `getOutputVO()` ?

Comment: yes sebastian currently we have 2. In future it will increase to 100 dao objects